# GCP Monitoring Groups - Group by Label Works in Some Projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I have two projects in GCP; I use one as a test environment, the other as a production environment. When I create a new Monitoring Group in my test project I have the option for "Tag" in the Type field of the "New Criterion" box. By selecting that, I'm able to specify Labels I wish to filter by for inclusion in the new group.

In my production project, I do not have the "Tag" option in the Type field dropdown:
[image]

I've confirmed that I have equivalent resources in both environments labelled the same. Why do I not have the "Tag" option in one of my projects?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/groups#membership_criteria), for Tags to be available on your second project, a secondary menu of resource values that are dependent on your configuration is displayed, and Tag names should be lower case

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and raised with Qwiklabs. The response I got is to wait for the labels to get saved properly which is a prior task of create group using tags.